# Why am I getting this "Invalid hook call" error here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Based on an array, I'm trying to create audio elements and [Slider][1]s to control their volume:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Slider from 'rc-slider';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';

function App() {
  const initialAudioSources = [
    { src: '/fire.mp3', volume: 1 },
    { src: '/ocean.mp3', volume: 1 },
    // Add more audio sources as needed
  ];

  const [audios, setAudios] = useState([]);
  const audioRefs = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create audio elements and set initial volume for each audio source
    const audioElements = initialAudioSources.map((audioSource) => {
      const audio = new Audio(audioSource.src);
      audio.volume = audioSource.volume;
      audio.loop = true;
      return audio;
    });

    setAudios(audioElements);
    audioRefs.current = audioElements.map(() => useRef(null));

    // Start playing the audios
    audioElements.forEach((audio, index) => {
      if (audioRefs.current[index].current) {
        audioRefs.current[index].current.volume = audio.volume;
        audioRefs.current[index].current.play();
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSliderChange = (newValue, index) => {
    const updatedAudios = audios.map((audio, i) => {
      if (i === index && audioRefs.current[i].current) {
        audioRefs.current[i].current.volume = newValue / 100;
      }
      return audio;
    });

    setAudios(updatedAudios);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="audio-controls">
        {audios.map((audio, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="audio-control">
            <audio ref={audioRefs.current[index]} controls>
              <source src={initialAudioSources[index].src} type="audio/mpeg" />
              Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
            <div className="slider-wrapper">
              <Slider
                className="slider"
                min={0}
                max={100}
                step={1}
                value={audio.volume * 100}
                onChange={(newValue) => handleSliderChange(newValue, index)}
                vertical
              />
              <p>{audio.volume * 100}%</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rc-slider-custom-handle-warning-forked-sn237f?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A6%2C28)

Right now, I'm getting this error:

> Error Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>
> See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
> and fix this problem.

I'm confused, I'm not calling hooks outside of a function component. What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: _"What could be the problem and how to fix it?"_ is exactly the topic of [the page](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) the error message linked you to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `useRef` inside your `.map()` callback.

Simply use `null`:

```
    setAudios(audioElements);
    audioRefs.current = audioElements.map(() => null);
```

You might want to add some null checks too.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rc-slider-custom-handle-warning-forked-tnnv25?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A38%2C47